# how to concisely write this javascript to show/hide a list of elements?

Tags: css, for-loop, show-hide, javascript

How to write this type of code in loop? Actually I don't want to write the same same line again and again, Is their any way to compress this code? can we write this code in loop?

```
function showCandidates()
{document.getElementById("cand9").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand10").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand11").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand12").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand13").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand14").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("cand15").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("hide_cand").style.display="block";
document.getElementById("view_cand").style.display="none";
}

function hideCandidates()
{document.getElementById("cand9").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand10").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand11").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand12").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand13").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand14").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("cand15").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("hide_cand").style.display="none";
document.getElementById("view_cand").style.display="block";
}
```

Comment: for(var i=9;i<=15;i++) {document.getElementById("cand"+i).style.display = "block";}, now you got the idea...

Comment: I was tempted to propose something similar myself mshsayem but this isn't exactly scalable for rashtra if he were to add another 'cand16' element for example. And it doesn't deal with the 'hide_cand' and 'view_cand' elements.

Comment: Learn about [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Predefined_Core_Objects#Array_Object) and maybe [CSS classes](http://www.cssbasics.com/chapter_3_css_class.html).

Answer (score 1):

I suggest this way:

```
var show_ids = ["cand9", "cand10", "cand11"] // ... and so on

funciton showCandidates() {
    for (var index in show_ids) {
        var id = show_ids[index];
        document.getElementById(id).style.display="none";
    }
}
```

similar for `hideCandidates`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign to your html elements a class for example

`<div class="hideable" >content </div>`

Then either you use JQuery or plain javascript to get all the elements that have the "hideable class attribute:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('hideable')
```

or

```
>$(".hideable")
```

Since your the two previous methods will return an array, you will have to loop through the array and apply the appropriate style attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this can be all encapsulated into one function. The function can take a parameter to assign to the display property. And obviously use some if statement in there to deal with the view_cand elements' display.

I would look into using jquery for this though, it makes selecting DOM elements (especially sets of DOM elements) a damn site easier.

I'd write the code for you here but I don't know anything about the elements you're selecting or the structure to your DOM.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

`for(i=0;i<candNumber;i++){`

`id= "cand" + i;`

`document.getElementById(id).style.display="block";`

`}`

Answer (score 0):

I hope this helps:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  var candidates = {
    idx: 0,
    getElement: function(id) { return document.getElementById(id); },

    toggle: function(elmnts, obj) {
      var idx = candidates.idx,
          getElement = function(id) { return candidates.getElement(id); };

      if (elmnts.length) {
        while ( idx < elmnts.length ) {
          getElement(elmnts[idx]).style.display = obj.display;
          idx++;
        }
      }
    }
  };

  var idsToHide = [
    "cand9", "cand10", "cand11", "cand12",
    "cand13", "cand14", "cand15", "hide_cand"
  ];
  var idsToShow = [
    "cand9", "cand10", "cand11", "cand12",
    "cand13", "cand14", "cand15", "hide_cand"
  ];

  function showCandidates() {
      candidates.toggle(idsToShow, {
          display: "block" 
      });
      candidates.toggle(["view_cand"], { display: "none" });
  }
  function hideCandidates() {
      candidates.toggle(idsToHide, {
          display: "none"
      });
      candidates.toggle(["view_cand"], { display: "block" });
   }
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

[Try this](http://jsfiddle.net/wBtmK/) .It'll hide/show ( the wayas you requested) by parameter given to function.

```
    setVisibilityByClass("visible"/"invisible") - shows/hides by changing class
    setVisibility("block"/"none") - shows/hides by changing styles directly
CHOOSE ONLY ONE.
```

css classes:

> .vissible{ display: block; } .invissible{ display: none; }

Js functions:

```
function setVisibility(val) {
    var not = new Array;
    not["none"] = "block";
    not["block"] = "none";
    for (i = 9; i <= 15; i++){
        document.getElementById("cand" + i).style.display = val;
    }
    document.getElementById("hide_cand").style.display = val;
    document.getElementById("view_cand").style.display = not[val];
}
function setVisibilityByClass(val) {
    var not = new Array;
    not["invissible"] = "vissible";
    not["vissible"] = "invissible";
    for (i = 9; i <= 15; i++){
        document.getElementById("cand" + i).setAttribute("class", val);
    }
    document.getElementById("hide_cand").setAttribute("class", val);
    document.getElementById("view_cand").setAttribute("class", not[val]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Easy to do with jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#candidates").toggle(function (){
        $(this).text('Hide Candidates');
        $.each($('.candidate'), function() {
            $(this).show();
        });
    }, function() {
        $(this).text('Show Candidates');
        $.each($('.candidate'), function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<a href="#" id="candidates">Show Candidates</a>

<div class='candidate' id='1'>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div class='candidate' id='2'>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
<div class='candidate' id='3'>
    <h1>Hello</h1>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.candidate { display: none }
```

Here's a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vbh5T/

If you don't want to use jQuery then please ignore my answer.

Comment: Note that this will iterate over the entire DOM on each invocation of the handler.

Comment: Still a cleaner solution than yours, nonetheless.

Comment: Not really, and especially not if you care about performance.

Comment: We're showing and hiding `divs`. we're not doing quantum mechanics calculations. I said the answer is cleaner, not more performant (not that he's going to notice anyway)

Comment: Your solution is neither cleaner nor better on any objective criterion; quite the reverse. The performance characteristics will matter on any page with a reasonable number of elements.

Answer (score -1):

(1) First of all, doing these kinds of lookups is best done with jquery. Apart from being easier (see code below), it also allows you pre-calculate the set of elements to act on. This matters, because lookups by ID scan the whole document tree. Accordingly, the more elements in the page, the slower it is to recalculate the set of elements to act on.

(2) Rather than setting individual properties, it is much better to use a css class.

```
<style>
 .invisible {display:none !important;}
</style>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"> // <![CDATA[


$(document).ready(function(){  


var hide = function(i) {i.addClass('invisible');};
var show = function(i) {i.removeClass('invisible');};


var candidates = $("#cand9, #cand10 /* etc. [...] */");
/* or, if you rejig this to set a class on all candidate elements:
var candidates = $(".candidate"); */

var hide_cand = $("#hide_cand");
var view_cand = $("#view_cand");
function showCandidates()
{
    show(candidates);
    show(view_cand);
    hide(hide_cand);
}

});  
// ]]>
</script>
```

I leave the corresponding `hideCandidates` as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: You know if they all had the same class name he could loop them in jquery just by using the selector `$(".candidate")`, right?

Comment: @Flukey: Sure, but that isn't the question that was asked.

Comment: Yes, it is, he could keep the same ids he has listed, but use a class on those elements and then do a class select in jquery to show and hide (just like in my answer) In your method, every time he adds a new candidate, he'll have to update the candidates variable in the JS. Not exactly efficient.

Comment: @Flukey: Actually, given that you query the class inside your function, your version will have worse (potentially significantly) worse performance. But, in any case, you are re-writing the question so you can answer one that you like.

Comment: How will it have worse performance? WHen querying the dom, it will know for example there are 4 elements with the class name of 'candidate' and then do the subsequent loop and then show or hide each element respectively. And if he's taking these candidates out of a database (which I assume he is) it will have be dynamic. Your solution isn't dynamic.  And there really isn't any need for jQuery in your example.

Comment: @Flukey: As already explained, your solution iterates over the entire DOM on each invocation. Using query as I have done both improves performance and concision.

Comment: Why are you using `!important` in the CSS? there is no need. Why are you not using event listeners? instead OP will now use `onClick='showCandidates(); return false;` if you're using jQuery, take advantage of it and use the event listeners. And using toggle is for this task. Why bother adding and removing a class? you could just use `.hide()` and `.show()` I will however concede that implicitly listing the ids is more efficient than a class selection, however, you're not exactly going to notice that efficiency problem until you start having hundred of elements to show and hide.

Comment: @Flukey: You don't know what other CSS is present in OP's page; I'm not using event listeners because...OP doesn't ask about event listeners, or show them in his code.

Comment: @Flukey: Performance is linear in the number of elements in the page, not in the set selected. It's pretty clear you don't actually know how this works.

Comment: I know how it works. The bigger the DOM grows the less performant class selections become. Obviously.  Your code is ugly. It works indeed, but it's not exactly nice. I'm not going to continue this discussion.

Comment: @Flukey: Sorry, how is it ugly? It's faster, clearer, and shorter than your code.

Comment: PS. Instead of `show(view_cand);hide(hide_cand);` it should be `show(hide_cand); hide(show_cand);` Anyway, i was just copying pasting your code.

Comment: @Flukey: That's not actually my code. That's some code using my example you specifically cooked up to not work.

Comment: That is YOUR code. Look at it again. I have changed nothing, I have just added in the HTML and the hide function. Go ahead, try your code.

Comment: @Flukey: Just because you keep saying it, it doesn't make it my code.

Comment: Well, show me an example with your code. That is identical to your code. And yet you have the audacity to complain about mine. heh.

Comment: @Flukey: The problem with *your* jsfiddle is that you don't understand javascript scoping rules. Both functions are hidden by the block enclosing all of the code. See this jsfiddle, demonstrating the correct way to add a handler not in global scope: http://jsfiddle.net/GQVJp/9/

Comment: No I do understand. I was just demonstrating that your code doesn't work. Oh and NOW you decide to use events....what a surprise. Such hypocrisy. Bravo.

Comment: @Flukey: No, what you've demonstrated is that you can cook up an example where you deliberately don't call any of the code I wrote. I'm not sure what that demonstrates, except perhaps the content of character.

Comment: I asked you earlier about using events but you said "I'm not using event listeners because...OP doesn't ask about event listeners". But you must have known that not using an event would break the code. It's pretty damn obvious. You should have just added it in in the first place. You've just demonstrated that your code is flawed in the current state and now you're trying to blame it on someone else. Unbelievable. Well done.

Comment: @Flukey: OP doesn't ask about how to hook this into the event system. I also think you don't know what an event is.

Comment: He also didn't ask about using jQuery did he? If you're going to provide an example using jquery , you might as well include the event handlers. That's a given. And please do forgive me if I'm wrong but I'm pretty certain the on click handle is indeed an event. Thank you for being patronising.

Comment: Please take extended discussions to one of the [chat rooms](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) instead of using comments.

Comment: @Flukey: No, it's not a given at all that I would show code that is extraneous to the question asked. You're literally making up requirements so you can criticise me for not meeting your made up requirements.

Comment: @Marcin - yes  that's exactly what I'm doing...... ridiculous. Sheer arrogance and stubbornness. Nevertheless, enjoy the rest of your day.

Comment: @Flukey: How is it not what you're doing? Would you care to relate any of your criticisms to the actual question or to my code (rather than your made-up version of either)?

Comment: I posted a working example that works and downvoted, incidentally. You posted an example that didn't work. Enough said.

Comment: @Flukey: No, I posted code that works (better than yours, by any measure), then you posted a jsfiddle that didn't actually call any of my code in attempt to pretend that my code doesn't work.

Comment: "by any measure" heh. still ugly code though. at one point you're using anonymous functions and then you're using standard functions. Ugly. Inconsistent. Code. Conversation finished. Thanks.

Comment: @Flukey: So, your criticism of this code is that it contains two slightly different syntaxes for defining functions? You're a software engineering genius.

Comment: @Flukey: And a comedian too, unless you don't know what sarcasm is.